# How do I join 2 tables to create a new instance of an object using linq/lambda expressions in Entity Framework Core in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core with PostGreSQL in an ASP.NET Core Web API.

I'm having difficulty figuring out the appropriate lambda/linq expression for
populating a field from a query.

I could do it long hand with a foreach() loop, but I'm sure there's a more efficient way to complete the task.

Consider the following table definitions:

```
public class A
{
    [Key]
    public Guid AId { get; set; }
    public string AName { get; set; }
    public Guid BId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] 
    public B BType { get; set; }
}

public class Consumer
{
    [Key]
    public Guid BId { get; set; }
    public string BName { get; set; }
    public string OtherInfo { get; set; }
}

public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }

public A GetAById(Guid p_Id)
{
    A result = null;

    using (Scope scope = AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(_container))
    {
        var dbContext = _container.GetInstance<FooDBContext>();
        result = dbContext.As.Where(x => x.AId == p_Id).FirstOrDefault();
        // How would I populate A->B with corresponding value from Bs Table?
    }

    return result;
}

result = dbContext.As.Where(x => x.AId == p_Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

How would I populate `A -> B` with corresponding value from Bs table?

I assume that I would do some sort of select and project results into a new instance of **A**?

Comment: You need a for loop.  Linq is a query and doesn allow writing to an existing object, just create a new output.

Comment: What do you mean with "populate" is `A.B` null or do you actually want to WRITE values into `A.B`?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can you show how you populate it now, pls?

Comment: Well, the short answer is - remove the `[NotMapped]` attribute and let EF Core populate it for you using one of the available methods for [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/). Otherwise why are you using EF Core at all :-/